# Подключение стандартных библиотек функций в GCC

Tags: gcc, библиотеки

Для подключения библиотеки стандартных математических функций, описанную в `<math.h>` (`libm.a`), требуется указать опцию компилятора `-lm`.
Какие ещё из стандартных библиотек требуют непосредственного подключения руками?

Comment: Если используются POSIX threads, то надо указать опцию `-pthread`

Comment: А что значит из "стандартных"? (@mikillskegg у меня в /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu более полутора сотен библиотек, так "стандартная" из них одна?)

Comment: ещё для использования потоков нужно.
А для всего другого есть `pkg-config`. С помощью `pkg-config --list-all` смотрим список установленных библиотек, а потом `pkg-config --libs --cflags имя_библиотеки`.
И конечно всякие qmake, cmake умеют сами все добавлять, им только укажи имена библиотек.

Comment: -lrt для clock_gettime() и т.п., -ldl для dlopen(), больше ничего в голову не приходит.

Кстати, по крайне мере в ubuntu для sqrt(), sin() и т.д. -lm **не нужно**.

Comment: @avp, я так понимаю, это те, которые описываются в стандарте языка Си. Ни pthread, ни librt, ни другие POSIX-библиотеки туда не входят.